# Scipy curve fit "array must not contain infs or NaNs"

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I'm trying to fit data with scipy curve_fit and keep geeting the ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs

Any ideas what could be wrong with my code?

```
df['kKfz_gesamt'] = (df['qKfz_gesamt'] / df['vKfz_gesamt'])

df1 = df.loc[(df.index >= '2018-01-01') & (df.index < '2018-01-31')]
df1 = df1.loc[(df.Status == 'SR_CLOSE')]
df2 = df1.resample('5min').mean().dropna()

k1 = df2.kKfz_gesamt
v1 = df2.vKfz_gesamt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(k1,v1,s=2,label='nach',color='blue')


### Fit
v0 = 125
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
def func(v, c1, c2, c3):
    return 1 / (c1 + (c2/(v0 - x)) + c3 * v)

xdata = v1
ydata = k1

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, p0=[0.1,0.1,0.1],maxfev=5000)
plt.plot(xdata, func(xdata, *popt), 'r-',label='fit: a=%5.3f, b=%5.3f, c=%5.3f' % tuple(popt))
popt
```

df2.info() gives:

```
DatetimeIndex: 7309 entries, 2018-01-01 01:00:00 to 2018-12-31 23:00:00
Data columns (total 11 columns):
 #   Column       Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------       --------------  -----  
 0   qKfz_2ÜFS    7309 non-null   float64
 1   qKfz_1ÜFS    7309 non-null   float64
 2   qKfz_HFS     7309 non-null   float64
 3   qKfz_TSF     7309 non-null   float64
 4   qKfz_gesamt  7309 non-null   float64
 5   vKfz_gesamt  7309 non-null   float64
 6   qLkw_gesamt  7309 non-null   float64
 7   vPkw_gesamt  7309 non-null   float64
 8   count_open   7309 non-null   float64
 9   count_close  7309 non-null   float64
 10  kKfz_gesamt  7309 non-null   float64
´´´
```

Comment: Please post the result of `df2.info()`

Comment: Thank you. I posted the results just now. Does it help?

Comment: I think something is going wrong with func() function as it is returning 1/something and that may result in infs when the denominator becomes zero and because of that maybe a ValueError is coming since it is givin inf for some values

Comment: There is for sure something wrong with your `def func`. The function arguments are `def func(v, c1, c2, c3):` where the 1st one needs to be the independent variable. So 1) is `v` or `x` the independent variable? 2) `x` is used in the function but not defined in the function arguments; 3) `v0` is used inside the function but defined outside and not defined in the arguments. So A) fix the function passing ALL parameters and variables as arguments; B) done this, you have to check your function domain as @PATHIKGHUGARE says, you need to exclude the singularity where denominator == 0